# WPF equivalent of Control.CursorChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, cursor

I am trying to change my mouse cursor at certain point when I'm dragging my mouse around in a wpf listview. However, when I set my mouse, it quickly gets overridden by something else, and get changed back to the drag cursor.

I am not sure where the cursor change comes from, it is certainly not from my code, so it has to be system. If it is system, then I have to intercept the event for cursor change, and handle the event in order for the cursor to show what I want right?

So is there a WPF equivalent of this Control.CursorChanged event? Or perhaps there's some other way to approach this problem?

Edit:

here's part of my code

```
    private void SetDragCursor()
    {
        if (_badDragLoc)
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.No;
        }
        else
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }
    }
    private void listView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (at a bad drag location)
        {
            _badDragLoc = true;
            SetDragCursor();
        }
    }
```

I also have a drag leave event handler, in which I also have the SetDragCursor() method as well. When I step by step go through each line of code in debugger, the mouse turned into the drag cursor from the no cursor right after it enters the drag leave handler. Which is why I think it has to be the system.

If it indeed is the system, then if I can capture the event firing, I can then handle those event myself and not let it bubble through.

Thank you!

Comment: Wrong approach.  If you use an event then the cursor will just start rapidly blinking between the two.  You're doing something wrong in "set my mouse", unguessable what it might be.  Post code.

Comment: Seen the [drag and drop overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx)? There might be something relevant in there about the cursor...

Comment: @Lin: don't care on how the cursors changes during a debug session.

Answer (score 1):

Just does not work like that, the way to set the cursor during a DragOver event is the following:

```
void listView__DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
     {
         if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent("Images"))
         {
             e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
             e.Handled = true;
         }
     }
```

depending on the value of DragDropEffects enum you assign to `e.Effects` the mouse will change cursor.

do not call `Mouse.OverrideCursor` because is not the right way.

Comment: Ah this does work, before I didn't set handled to be true, so I guess something else modified it. However my cursor still flashes occasionally during drag over. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: I also figured out that changing the AllowDrop property will also change the cursor, however that will make me unable to interact with the item that is made to not allow drop. I need to interact with the item during DragOver event handler, so setting AllowDrop to be false isn't an option for me. Are there any other ways to change the cursor, or is there a way to make the cursor stop flickering? Thanks!